# CentOS Stream 9 with Apache 2.4.57 and PHP 8.2.6, cURL 7.76.1 not working in PHP but works via console

Tags: php, apache, curl, centos

I have a server running CentOS Stream 9 with Apache 2.4.57 and PHP 8.2.6.

cURL 7.76.1 is enabled and confirmed via `phpinfo()` but when I use php to make a cURL request, it comes back empty and an error is thrown. However, if I use curl via terminal to make the same request, it gets the content without issue.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, any help would be super appreciated.

**Here is my test.php file:**

```php
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://catfact.ninja/fact");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}

curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

**Output:**

```text
cURL error (7): Couldn't connect to server
```

**Here is the code I run in the console:**

```text
[user@server ~]$ curl https://catfact.ninja/fact
```

**Output:**

```
{"fact":"The average litter of kittens is between 2 - 6 kittens.","length":55}
```

Comment: curl utility you call via console and curl library used in php are two completely different things

Comment: probably you want to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` before you call `curl_exec` in php

Comment: and there is no reason for 2nd call to `curl_exec`, just use result from first call

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out - SELinux was blocking the request.

As a solution, I could either setup a proxy in cURL or check if SELinux `httpd_can_network_connect` is enabled. Check by running `getsebool -a | grep httpd` You can enable it by running `$ setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Please consider the security implementations of allowing `httpd_can_network_connect` which I will not go into here. I hope this helps someone else!